# Appending API Json data creates siblings instead of children within children

Tags: jquery

Html Structure

```
<div class="teams-wrap">
    <div class='single-team-wrap'>
        <h3 class='team-title'>
            Team Title
        </h3>
        <div class="single-team-position">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="single-team-position">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="single-team-position">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
function (data) {
    var data = data.departments;
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      if (item.jobs.length > 0) {
        var teamWrap = $('.teams-wrap').append(
          '<div class="single-team-wrap"></div>'
        );
        var newDept = (teamWrap).append(
          '<h3 class="team-title">' +
            item.name +
            "</h3></div>"
        );
        $.each(item.jobs, function (i, jobs) {
          $(teamWrap).append(
            '<p>' + jobs.title + '</p>'
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Basically I want for each Team(single-team-wrap) to create a div with that class and in it have the H3 "team-title" and as siblings to the H3 each single team position. Right now the current result I get is that under teams-wrap I get single-team-wrap as a child, and the rest as children too, basically they all become siblings. single-team-wrap is a sibling to team-title and to every single-team-position.

I want each div appended to be inbetween the  of the var. Looking at it there should be a way to insert it directly there but I'm totally clueless on what to do. I tried appendTo, after, insertAfter but nothing gets the result I'm looking for.

Comment: You have invalid HTML here `<div class="single-team-wrap></div>`

Comment: My bad. This is a simplified version of my code. Everything is valid and works I just can't get it to append as child to each div each time.

Comment: `var teamWrap = $(XYZ).append(..)` will return `XYZ` as `teamWrap` ie `.teams-wrap` - I'm guessing you want that to be `single-team-wrap` - so use `.appendTo` with XYZ as the element you want to append:   `var teamWrap = $("<div class='single-team-wrap'>").appendTo(".teams-wrap")` - now teamWrap will be the new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error however might I suggest you hit the DOM less, once per team and create interim objects instead.  I renamed a few things to make it more clear perhaps.

```js
function doStuff(data) {
  var dep = data.departments;
  var teams = $('.teams-wrap');
  $.each(dep, function(i, item) {
    if (item.jobs.length > 0) {
      let teamWrap = $('<div class="single-team-wrap"></div>');
      $('<h3 class="team-title">' + item.name + "</h3>").appendTo(teamWrap);
      $.each(item.jobs, function(j, job) {
        $('<p>' + job.title + '</p>').appendTo(teamWrap);
      });
      teams.append(teamWrap);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teams-wrap">
  <div class='single-team-wrap'>
    <h3 class='team-title'>
      Team Title
    </h3>
    <div class="single-team-position">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="single-team-position">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="single-team-position">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! This makes total sense and it worked like a charm. I was so stuck in my ways never though of another way to do it.